# how can I calculate recall, precision and f-score for this model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been working on implementing this model for months now and finally get it to work. Now I was looking to calculate metrics for this model like F-score, Recall, Precision etc. I looked at examples and they do it by splitting data which I've not been able to implement. Can I calculate it like model loss and total loss is calculated here???

```
from nets import model
from utils.data_provider import data_provider
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
gpus = list(range(len(FLAGS.gpu_list.split(','))))

logger.setLevel(cfg.debug)

def tower_loss(images, seg_maps_gt, training_masks, reuse_variables=None):
    # Build inference graph
    with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=reuse_variables):
        seg_maps_pred = model.model(images, is_training=True)

    model_loss = model.loss(seg_maps_gt, seg_maps_pred, training_masks)
    total_loss = tf.add_n([model_loss] + tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES))

    # add summary
    if reuse_variables is None:
        tf.summary.image('input', images)
        tf.summary.image('seg_map_0_gt', seg_maps_gt[:, :, :, 0:1] * 255)
        tf.summary.image('seg_map_0_pred', seg_maps_pred[:, :, :, 0:1] * 255)
        tf.summary.image('training_masks', training_masks)
        tf.summary.scalar('model_loss', model_loss)
        tf.summary.scalar('total_loss', total_loss)

    return total_loss, model_loss


def average_gradients(tower_grads):
    average_grads = []
    for grad_and_vars in zip(*tower_grads):
        grads = []
        for g, _ in grad_and_vars:
            expanded_g = tf.expand_dims(g, 0)
            grads.append(expanded_g)

        grad = tf.concat(grads, 0)
        grad = tf.reduce_mean(grad, 0)

        v = grad_and_vars[0][1]
        grad_and_var = (grad, v)
        average_grads.append(grad_and_var)

    return average_grads


def main(argv=None):
    import os
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = FLAGS.gpu_list
    if not tf.gfile.Exists(FLAGS.checkpoint_path):
        tf.gfile.MkDir(FLAGS.checkpoint_path)
    else:
        if not FLAGS.restore:
            tf.gfile.DeleteRecursively(FLAGS.checkpoint_path)
            tf.gfile.MkDir(FLAGS.checkpoint_path)

    input_images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None, 3], name='input_images')
    input_seg_maps = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None, 6], name='input_score_maps')
    input_training_masks = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, None, None, 1], name='input_training_masks')

    global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)
    learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(FLAGS.learning_rate, global_step, decay_steps=10000, decay_rate=0.94, staircase=True)
    # add summary
    tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', learning_rate)
    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)

    # split
    input_images_split = tf.split(input_images, len(gpus))
    input_seg_maps_split = tf.split(input_seg_maps, len(gpus))
    input_training_masks_split = tf.split(input_training_masks, len(gpus))

    tower_grads = []
    reuse_variables = None
    for i, gpu_id in enumerate(gpus):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % gpu_id):
            with tf.name_scope('model_%d' % gpu_id) as scope:
                iis = input_images_split[i]
                isegs = input_seg_maps_split[i]
                itms = input_training_masks_split[i]
                total_loss, model_loss = tower_loss(iis, isegs, itms, reuse_variables)
                batch_norm_updates_op = tf.group(*tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS, scope))
                reuse_variables = True

                grads = opt.compute_gradients(total_loss)
                tower_grads.append(grads)

    grads = average_gradients(tower_grads)
    apply_gradient_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)

    summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
    # save moving average
    variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(
        FLAGS.moving_average_decay, global_step)
    variables_averages_op = variable_averages.apply(tf.trainable_variables())
    # batch norm updates
    with tf.control_dependencies([variables_averages_op, apply_gradient_op, batch_norm_updates_op]):
        train_op = tf.no_op(name='train_op')

    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(FLAGS.checkpoint_path, tf.get_default_graph())

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    if FLAGS.pretrained_model_path is not None:
        variable_restore_op = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(FLAGS.pretrained_model_path, slim.get_trainable_variables(),
                                                             ignore_missing_vars=True)
    gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)
    #gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.75)
    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options, allow_soft_placement=True)) as sess:
        if FLAGS.restore:
            logger.info('continue training from previous checkpoint')
            ckpt = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(FLAGS.checkpoint_path)
            logger.debug(ckpt)
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt)
        else:
            sess.run(init)
            if FLAGS.pretrained_model_path is not None:
                variable_restore_op(sess)

        data_generator = data_provider.get_batch(num_workers=FLAGS.num_readers,
                                                 input_size=FLAGS.input_size,
                                                 batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size_per_gpu * len(gpus))

        start = time.time()
        for step in range(FLAGS.max_steps):
            data = next(data_generator)
            ml, tl, _ = sess.run([model_loss, total_loss, train_op], feed_dict={input_images: data[0],
                                                                                input_seg_maps: data[2],
                                                                                input_training_masks: data[3]})
            if np.isnan(tl):
                logger.error('Loss diverged, stop training')
                break

            if step % 10 == 0:
                avg_time_per_step = (time.time() - start)/10
                avg_examples_per_second = (10 * FLAGS.batch_size_per_gpu * len(gpus))/(time.time() - start)
                start = time.time()
                logger.info('Step {:06d}, model loss {:.4f}, total loss {:.4f}, {:.2f} seconds/step, {:.2f} examples/second'.format(
                    step, ml, tl, avg_time_per_step, avg_examples_per_second))

            if step % FLAGS.save_checkpoint_steps == 0:
                saver.save(sess, os.path.join(FLAGS.checkpoint_path, 'model.ckpt'), global_step=global_step)

            if step % FLAGS.save_summary_steps == 0:
                _, tl, summary_str = sess.run([train_op, total_loss, summary_op], feed_dict={input_images: data[0],
                                                                                             input_seg_maps: data[2],
                                                                                             input_training_masks: data[3]})
                summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, global_step=step)
```

Sorry for posting bunch of code lines but I really have no idea how to calculate metrics from all this?

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn has a great API for calculating precision, recall and F1 score for each class:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html

```
Y_pred = sess.run([nn_output], feed_dict={input_images: input_data[0], input_seg_maps: input_data[2], input_training_masks: input_data[3]]}) # Feed according to your model
ClassificationReport = sklearn.metrics.classification_report(Y_pred, Y_true, output_dict=True)
```

Comment: I don't understand how to implement it for my code. what should be my y_true? And where do I use this code in my code?

Comment: do I need to provide ground truth as [nn_output]? I think I understand y_true will be ground truth and y_pred will be calculated here but I still can't implement it here